# How to find element created by createElementNS?

Tags: javascript

### What I do wrong here?

```
var parent = document.createDocumentFragment();
var child = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'Child')
parent.appendChild(child);

var result = parent.querySelector('Child'); //null
```

I also tried to search by `parent.querySelector('*|Child')`, it also don't work for me.

Can I read anywhere why I can't find tag in this situation?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There may be more convenient ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: I have an XML file what I create on the fly. As input I have css-style string `:scope>DB>Item[name="Dog"]`, I need to convert this string to XML part and in future to find `Item` tag (or all `Item` tags)

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/d7e3813089ed12a827863b1c19ca335fa0d1e284%5E!/ tell me that namespaces are not supported by queryselector